# What is meant by $\left| A \right| = \sqrt{A^{\ast}A}$

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I've been reading bounded operators in Hilbert/Banach spaces and have come across the notation $\left| A \right| = \sqrt{A^{\ast}A}$ for some operator $A$. I haven't really found a good explanation about what this means for an operator however.

In particular what this would mean for a self adjoint operator $A$. I don't think we would simply have that $\left| A \right| = \sqrt{A^{\ast}A} = \sqrt{A^2} = A.$

Comment: You might be interested to learn about functional caculus. Given a continuous function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. There is a way to define $f(A)$ for certain operators $A$. The above fits into thi framework.

Comment: The square root of a positive operator is just the unique positive operator whose square is the original operator. There is a theorem that says it always exists.

Comment: This is an analogue of the absolute value of a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ , then $B:=A^{\ast}A$ is positive (this means $(Bx,x) \ge 0$ for all $ x \in H$).

One can show: there is exacrtly one positiv bounded linear operator $Q$ such that $Q^2=B$.

Then define: $|A|:=Q$

You are right, that we not always have

(*) $\left| A \right| = \sqrt{A^{\ast}A} = \sqrt{A^2} = A$ if $A$ is selfadiont.

(*) is only valid , if $A$ is positive